# How to print a Python dictionary values in a required order?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two python dictionary in my code dic_1 and dic_2.

```
dic_1 = {'key1': ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 'single']),
         'key2': ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 'single']),
         'key3': ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 'single'])}

dic_2 = {'key1': ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 'married']),
         'key2': ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 'married']),
         'key3': ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 'married'])}

for (key, value), (key2, value2) in zip(dic_1.items(), dic_2.items()):
    for (one, two, v2one, v2two, ) in zip(value[0], value[1], value2[0], value2[1]):
        print(key, one, two)
        print(key, v2one, v2two)
```

and I am getting output like this

```
key1 1 4
key1 1 4
key1 2 5
key1 2 5
key1 3 single
key1 3 married
key2 1 4
key2 1 4
key2 2 5
key2 2 5
key2 3 single
key2 3 married
key3 1 4
key3 1 4
key3 2 5
key3 2 5
key3 3 single
key3 3 married
```

My output is getting printed like this because of my print statement, but I am looking for output like this

```
key1 1 4
key1 2 5
key1 3 single
key1 1 4
key1 2 5
key1 3 married
key2 1 4
key2 2 5
key2 3 single
key2 1 4
key2 2 5
key2 3 married
key3 1 4
key3 2 5
key3 3 single
key3 1 4
key3 2 5
key3 3 married
```

How can I achieve this? I am not sure where I am making mistake, Thanks

Comment: Hi! What are you trying to print? be more specific about your desired output

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just get the keys in on dictionary and then get the corresponding elements with two zips and then print it. I am assuming that all keys in dict1 are in dict2.

```
from __future__ import print_function
dic_1 = {'key1': ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 'single']),
         'key2': ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 'single']),
         'key3': ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 'single'])}

dic_2 = {'key1': ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 'married']),
         'key2': ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 'married']),
         'key3': ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 'married'])}
for key in sorted(dic_1.keys()):
    for one,two in zip(*dic_1[key]):
        print(key,one,two)

    for one,two in zip(*dic_2[key]):
        print(key,one,two)
```

OUTPUT

```
key1 1 4
key1 2 5
key1 3 single
key1 1 4
key1 2 5
key1 3 married
key2 1 4
key2 2 5
key2 3 single
key2 1 4
key2 2 5
key2 3 married
key3 1 4
key3 2 5
key3 3 single
key3 1 4
key3 2 5
key3 3 married
```